# Android: save file to sdcard?

Tags: android, file, permissions, download, sd-card

I am attempting to create a program that saves an mp3 to the Android, which can be accessed by ASTRO. I am attempting to save the file to /sdcard/media/audio. Despite the app going through without a single error on Logcat/DDMS, the file is nowhere to be found. I added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (along with Internet, etc.) so it's not that.

Are there restrictions for apps saving files to the sdcard?

Method called:

```
public void findSong(View view) throws Exception {
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);          
    searchTerm = edittext.getText().toString();
    String address;         
    address = getMusic(searchTerm);         
    ImageManager img = new ImageManager(); //calls ImageManager (below)         
    img.DownloadFromUrl(address, title + ".mp3"); 
}
```

The downloading method:

```
private final String PATH = "/data/data";  //put the downloaded file here

public void DownloadFromUrl(String imageURL, String fileName) {  
//this is the downloader method

try {
    URL url = new URL(imageURL); //you can write here any link
    File file = new File(fileName);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.d("ImageManager", "download begining");
    Log.d("ImageManager", "download url:" + url);
    Log.d("ImageManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);

    /* Open a connection to that URL. */
    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

    /* Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection. */
    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

    /* Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1). */
    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
    int current = 0;
    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
        baf.append((byte) current);
    }

   /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATH + file);
   fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
   fos.close();
   Log.d("ImageManager", "download ready in"
       + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
       + " sec");
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
   }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try something simply like writing out a dummy text file with static content that doesn't have to be downloaded in your onCreate() - Not normally a good idea, but you are just going to have it in your code for a few minutes to verify that you've figured out how to write files.

Comment: Your code shows you are putting the file in '/data/data' but your question mentions you are putting it in '/sdcard/media/audio'

Answer (score 2):

If the file is an mp3 you should do:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));
```

This will foce an scan and make it available in the media player.

Comment: Yes, to bring it to the attention of the media player, but Astro doesn't care as it is a file manager.

Comment: Cool, I did this and I do find a file in the folder. However, it is called "null.mp3" and is just nothing. But that is some huge help for sure. Where should this line be located? Maybe that's why its null. I put it at the very end of DownloadfromURL.